# maximum limit of data can be store in request.setAttribute in jsp?

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

i'm using setAttribute in jsp for storing data (objects) . i'm worry about limit of setAttribute. if we can changing the limit , what is the solution?

Comment: What is the size of data you are trying to store?

Comment: nice question. Interested to know myself. Couldn't find any info on it.

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy , i am using for multi part of related data to logged in user. one part of this is 1mb .

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte thanks for your attention. perhaps setAttribute doesn't have any limitation.